# The equation $x^T A x = (x^2)^T A x^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

Let $x$ be a positive vector and let $x^2$ denote the vector whose elements are the squares of the elements of $x$. Let $A$ be a positive symmetric matrix. Is it true that if $$x^T A x = (x^2)^T A x^2$$ then $x$ is the all-ones vector?

Comment: That is false even for $x, A$ scalars  ($1 \times 1$ size)

Comment: @leonbloy No, then you are looking at $ax^2=ax^4$ which has only one positive solution.

Comment: @Ian You're right, I misread the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $A=I_2$ and $x=(a,b)$ with $a^2+b^2=a^4+b^4$, so for example $a=\sqrt{0.5},b=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}/\sqrt{2}$.